# How to correctly link collections in MongoDB/Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I am currently developing a Questionbank and I would like to link test results to user accounts. I am new to the noSQL database structure and I just wanted an opinion from the experts as to the best way to link the results to the user.

Should I have the userSchema to have a reference to a user specific test score collection? Or just link to keys in a global collection of test scores with "ref:"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should think data which your need as a JSON and other entities as a properties and property array.

I hope this code will help you:

Question:

```
{
   "title" : "It's a title of question",
   "otherProperty" : Boolean,
   "created_by: {
      "name": "User Who Created Question",
      "otherProperty":0
   },
   "answers": [
      {"text":"Answer content", 
       "created_by": {
          "name":"User Who Answered Question
        }, 
       "otherProperty":False
      },
      {"text":"Answer content", 
       "created_by": {
          "name":"User Who Answered Question
        }, 
       "otherProperty":False
      },
      {"text":"Answer content", 
       "created_by": {
          "name":"User Who Answered Question
        }, 
       "otherProperty":False
      }
   ]
}
```

In side of code you should read mongoose docs but you will use `Ref` key usually. Like this:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var QuestionSchema = new Schema({
   title: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   answers: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Answer'
   }]
})

var Answer = new Schema({
   text: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   created_by: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
   }
})
```

I hope it will help you.

UPDATE: I just updated sample code for first example.

Comment: Thank you @Furkan, but would it not be better to have the data presented in a different way? So that you use a separate collection which would hold all the tests answered, and link back to the questions?
`{
   "title" : "Test Category 1",
   "answered_by: {
      "name": "User Who Took the Test"
   },
   "marksheet": [
      {"text":"Answer content", 
       "Question": "ObjectId",
       "Correct": True,
}
]
} `